# Installation Issue Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I'm having an issue with getting Ubuntu 14.04 to load into the GUI after installation.  I get through the installation with no problems, the computer boots up and the Ubuntu logo appears on the screen.  I get to the login screen, but after that I just get dots on the screen.  Could someone help me out on this issue?  I have tried doing the full installation 3 times with the same result.

Comment: Please add an image of the last state you are in so that we can have a clear idea..

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by following these instructions:

Comment: 1.Put your installation media into the computer
2.Switch on the computer
3.Press the spacebar as soon as the picture of the keyboard and human display at the bottom of the screen
4.Choose your language
5.Select “Try Ubuntu without any changes”
6.Press F6
7.Select “nomodeset”
8.Press Escape (Esc)
9.Type: "1915.modeset=0 xforcevesa"


10.Press Enter (Return) and be amazed as Ubuntu loads.

Comment: I believe that the issue was due to the fact that I was installing on an older computer and the graphics card was having issues loading Ubuntu.  All is well and good now and I'm able to boot into the system with no problems.

Comment: Its great to hear that your problem is resolved. Please put the above steps you mentioned in the comment as an answer to the question so that this issue can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by following these instructions:

1. Put your installation media into the computer
2. Switch on the computer
3. Press the spacebar as soon as the picture of the keyboard and human display at the bottom of the screen
4. Choose your language
5. Select **Try Ubuntu without installing**
6. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>
7. Select **nomodeset**
8. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>
9. Type: `1915.modeset=0 xforcevesa`
10. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> and be amazed as Ubuntu loads.

I believe that the issue was due to the fact that I was installing on an older computer and the graphics card was having issues loading Ubuntu. All is well and good now and I'm able to boot into the system with no problems.